# Oracle’s Driver (Thin XA) for Application Continuity configuring with tomcat pool

Tags: oracle, datasource

I needed to use driver-class-name as : **oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl** in a spring boot application.

I wanted to create a **org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.XADataSource** using the above driver. But I am running into the following error :

Unable to create a new JDBC connection.
java.sql.SQLException: class oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl cannot be cast to class java.sql.Driver (oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleXADataSourceImpl is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.sql.Driver is in module java.sql of loader 'platform')

Does anyone have an idea how to create a tomcate datasource  pool from Oracle XA driver?

Comment: Im not sure whether Application continuity is supported with XA. There were times when this was not possible. And I'm not sure whether it got changed. Do you have a reason why do you need distributed transactions? 
BTW: Apache is shipped with two connection pooling libraries - those are quite limited. Spring uses HikariCP which is smarter. And if you use Oracle RAC database I recommend to to use UCP.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to tomcat/lib folder => library conflict with your JDBC Connection Management.

Make sure to match the excluded libraries (jar's) in the POM.xml dependencies with the tomcat/lib folder (jar's).

Spring-boot has the capability to induce the default database connection management and so as tomcat too.

When there is a customisation, we need to make sure the sync up the application server & Application dependencies.

Hope this helps your problem.

Cheers!